# Python scipy module derivate not working with input from user

Tags: python

When I tried to calculate a derivate from an user it gave me an error, that says that derivate does not take string inputs, but so how  Ican achieve this

```
import scipy.misc import derivate

fx=input()
print(derivative(fx,1.0,dx=1e-8))
```

Comment: Import should be `from scipy.misc import derivative` and as per documentation fx should be function but in your case it's the user input

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter is `func`, not `str` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html). If you want it as input you can use `lambda` and `eval`. The input need to be in `x**3 + x**2` format

```
fx = input()
f = lambda x: eval(fx)

print(derivative(f, 1.0, dx=1e-8))
```

Comment: yeah but if i wanna change the x**3 + x**2 for some other function that my user want how i achieve this? i try like the example that you posted but doest work

Comment: OMG @Guy You are a legend! Thank you sooo muuuuuuch bro thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(x):
   return x**2 + x
print(derivative(f,1.0,dx=1e-6))
```

------------ Updated---------------------

Explanation: - With your code you have tried to pass a string  to the function derivative which expects a function instead , here is the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html)

Comment: the [derivative function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) needs a function as fx.

Comment: i mean fx is a function like 4*x**2 , not a integer so this doesnt work

Comment: Please don't copy other users answers.

Comment: @Guy - I have taken reference from the link that is tagged in my answer , so I don't see any issue in that

Comment: I think i need to explain myself more , yeah the derivate expresion expects a function and yeah i can type whatever function i want in the code and later compile and it works But what i wanna achieve is dont type the function in the code, but in the console like user input , but whatever i do this , python read the function i introduce like a string not a literal math function

Comment: @Guy - Again this has nothing to do with your post ,as I mentioned in my comment earlier , the source of the original code that is posed is given in the answer along